# How to change jelly form layout?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I am working on jenkin plugin.I have created one form using following jelly script.

```
<?jelly escape-by-default='true'?>
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler"  xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson"  xmlns:f="/lib/form">
<f:section title="Catalyst Login">
    <f:entry title="Catalyst Url" field="catUrl">
        <f:textbox />
    </f:entry>
    <f:entry title="Username" field="catUser">
        <f:textbox />
    </f:entry>
    <f:entry title="Password" field="catPass">
        <f:textbox />
    </f:entry>
    <f:validateButton
        title="${%Test Connection}" progress="${%Testing...}"
        method="testConnection" with="catUrl,catUser,catPass" />
</f:section>
</j:jelly>
```

This from layout is multiple row and one column.I mean only one input box displayed in one row.
Is it possible to have two input box in one row?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `table` where you can manipulate rows and columns count.

Example:

```
<?jelly escape-by-default='true'?>
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler"  xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson"  xmlns:f="/lib/form">
<f:section title="Catalyst Login">
    <table> 
        <tr>
            <td>
                <f:entry title="Username" field="catUser">
                    <f:textbox />
                </f:entry>
            </td>
            <td>
                <f:entry title="Password" field="catPass">
                    <f:textbox />
                </f:entry>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <f:validateButton
        title="${%Test Connection}" progress="${%Testing...}"
        method="testConnection" with="catUrl,catUser,catPass" />
</f:section>
</j:jelly>
```